# Trying to Count data with the same suffix in a table

Tags: sql-server

I have the code below and I'm trying to count data with the suffix "Fertilizer" and "pesticide" from a table in my SQL server database. The code is not working, what can be the problem

```
private string GetFarmInputCount()
{
    string ret = "_ _";
    string query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM Loan WHERE Name LIKE 'Fertilizer' AND 'Pesticide'";
    DataTable dt = QueryDatabase(query);

    foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        ret = row[0].ToString();
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: WHERE Name LIKE '%Fertilizer' OR Name LIKE '%Pesticide'

Answer (score 1):

You need to add wildcards to the strings you are trying to match so that SQL Server knows where to match additional characters. In this case, the wildcard is `%`, and you want to match cases where your strings are suffixes, so you need to put the wildcard at the beginning. Your query then should look like this:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM Loan WHERE Name LIKE '%Fertilizer' OR '%Pesticide'"
```

You can find more information in [the Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on how pattern matching with LIKE works, including other types of wildcards you can use.

Comment: Name cannot be in the same time Fertilizer and Pesticide, so there must be `OR` instead of `AND`.